# Mutation cache update not working with vue-apollo and Hasura

Tags: postgresql, vue.js, graphql, vue-apollo, hasura

I'm completely new to these technologies, and am having trouble wrapping my head around it, so bear with me. So, my situation is that I've deployed Hasura on Heroku and have added some data, and am now trying to implement some functionality where I can add and edit certain rows of a table. Specifically I've been following [this](https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/insert.html#) from Hasura, and [this](https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/mutations.html#server-side-example) from vue-apollo.

I've implemented the adding and editing (which works), and now want to also reflect this in the table, by using the `update` property of the mutation and updating the cache. Unfortunately, this is where I get lost. I'll paste some of my code below to make my problem more clear:

The mutation for adding a player (`ADD_PLAYER_MUTATION`) (same as the one in Hasura's documentation linked above):

```
mutation addPlayer($objects: [players_insert_input!]!) {
  insert_players(objects: $objects) {
    returning {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The code for the mutation in the `.vue` file

```
addPlayer(player, currentTimestamp) {
  this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: PLAYER_ADD_MUTATION,
    variables: {
      objects: [
        {
          name: player.name,
          team_id: player.team.id,
          created_at: currentTimestamp,
          updated_at: currentTimestamp,
          role_id: player.role.id,
          first_name: player.first_name,
          last_name: player.last_name
        }
      ]
    },
    update: (store, { data: { addPlayer } }) => {
      const data = store.readQuery({
        query: PLAYERS
      });
      console.log(data);
      console.log(addPlayer);
      data.players.push(addPlayer);
      store.writeQuery({ query: PLAYERS, data });
    }
  });
},
```

I don't really get the `update` part of the mutation. In most examples the  `{ data: { x } }` bit uses the function's name in the place of `x`, and so I did that as well, even though I don't really get why (it's pretty confusing to me at least). When logging `data` the array of players is logged, but when logging `addPlayer` `undefined` is logged.

I'm probably doing something wrong that is very simple for others, but I'm obviously not sure what. Maybe the mutation isn't returning the correct thing (although I'd assume it wouldn't log `undefined` in that case), or maybe isn't returning anything at all. It's especially confusing since the player *is* actually added to the database, so it's just the `update` part that isn't working - plus, most of the guides / tutorials show the same thing without really much explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so for anyone as stupid as me, here's basically what I was doing wrong:

- Instead of `addPlayer` in `update: (store, { data: { addPlayer } })`, it should be whatever the name of the mutation is, so in this case `insert_players`.
- By default a mutation response from Hasura has a `returning` field, which is a list, and so the added player is the first element in the list, so you can get it like so: `const addedPlayer = insert_players.returning[0];`

I didn't want to just delete my question after realising what was wrong shortly after posting it, in case this is useful to other people like me, and so I'll leave it up.